# Filtering ASP.NET membership roles without the default attributes

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net, authentication

I am building an application, and I needed an attribute *similar* to `AuthorizeAttribute`, supporting `Roles` but *not* using the `MembershipProvider` roles. (Basically, with the setup I have, I cannot rely on the `User.IsInRole` method - it's *not* always accurate, so I manually query the roles in my `MasterDbContext` instead.)

I have two different parts to it:

```
public class RequiredRoleAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; } = "~/Account/Login";

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var context = new MasterDbContext();
        var user = context.Users.Find(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        var requiredRoles = Roles.Split(',').Select(roleName => context.Roles.First(role => role.Name == roleName).Name).ToList();

        if (!requiredRoles.All(r => user.InRole(r, context)))
        {
            if (Destination == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Default", null);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Destination);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should be self-explanatory. It does the same thing as `[AuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "SomeString")]`, used in conjunction with that attribute:

```
[Authorize]
[RequiredRole(Roles = Constants.Roles.Moderators)]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public MasterDbContext Context { get; } = new MasterDbContext();
}
```

So that's easy. As you can see, I can *still* use `[Authorize]`, I just can't use `[Authorize(Roles = ...)]`.

Then, I wrote `User.InRole` instead of the `User.IsInRole` method:

```
public bool InRole(string roleName, MasterDbContext providedContext = null)
{
    var context = providedContext ?? new MasterDbContext();
    var roleId = context.Roles.First(r => r.Name == roleName).Id;
    return Roles.ToList().Any(r => roleId == r.RoleId);
}
```

Any/all comments welcome, this is another *huge* portion of this application and I would love to make it as effective as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> public abstract class BaseController : Controller
> {
>     public MasterDbContext Context { get; } = new MasterDbContext();
> }
> ```

I *really* don't like this. Every single controller class derived from `BaseController` has a public `IDisposable` dependency. That's taking *encapsulation* for a little "talk", outside, in a dark alley.

I can't think of a single reason `Context` would need to be `public` for. It should be `protected`.

But that's not the biggest issue. From the outside, say, from a derived class' point of view, inheriting from `BaseController` seems like a casual thing to do: the name suggests it, strongly.

Every derived controller inherits an `IDisposable` dependency *that it didn't ask for* - and since the base class creates it *and doesn't take its responsibilities* (he who creates an `IDisposable` instance, should be the one to call `Dispose`), if every derived type fails to override the controller's `Dispose` method, every single controller is leaking resources.

So you could implement `IDisposable.Dispose` in the `BaseController`.

Or, you could simply get rid of `BaseController` altogether. Disposable resources are important, they shouldn't be implicit. There's a very solidly (yet far from SOLID) tightly-coupled relationship between every controller and `MasterDbContext` - and that relationship is toxic.

There has to be a better way. This is more explicit:

```
[Authorize]
[RequiredRole(Roles = Constants.Roles.Moderator)]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private MasterDbContext Context { get; } = new MasterDbContext();

    // controller methods...

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && Context != null)
        {
            Context.Dispose();
            Context = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Now now, I hear you - "but what about DRY? I have to repeat that code in every controller?". No you don't.

What you *can* do, is make it *someone else's job* to create (and therefore to dispose) the context: you *tell* that "someone else" that you need a `MasterDbContext`, and let them deal with its lifetime.

```
[Authorize]
[RequiredRole(Roles = Constants.Roles.Moderator)]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly MasterDbContext _context

    public AdminController(MasterDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // controller methods...
}
```

Now anyone can look at that class and know that it requires a `Constants.Roles.Moderator` role, and that it has a `MasterDbContext` dependency. It's still coupled with a concrete type, but at least it's explicit about it. And we don't need to worry about disposing the context anymore - a controller that receives its `DbContext` through the constructor can happily assume that whoever put it there is going to dispose it when it destroys it.. and *exactly when* that happens is not its job either: the controller had nothing to do with *creating* the context.

This poses a problem though: the default controller factory requires a default constructor. And if you add one, then your context is always going to be `null`... which defeats the purpose of telling your caller that you have a dependency on `MasterDbContext`.

The solution is nothing less than implementing your own controller factory! Kidding. You can simply take an existing one - [ninject](/questions/tagged/ninject), for example, will substitute the default controller factory for one that uses the Ninject IoC container to create an instance per request and *inject* it into the controllers' constructors.

All that's left to do is to tell Ninject that whenever a controller requests a `MasterDbContext`, you give it a `MasterDbContext` instance. The registration code might look like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<MasterDbContext>().To<MasterDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

And from there, you're an inch away from being able to do this instead:

```
Kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<MasterDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

Which means your controllers can look like this:

```
[Authorize]
[RequiredRole(Roles = Constants.Roles.Moderator)]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _context

    public AdminController(IUnitOfWork context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // controller methods...
}
```

And here goes the "D" of SOLID:

> *Depend on abstractions, not on concrete types.*

The `IUnitOfWork` interface can be a simple, minimal wrapper for `DbContext`:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<T> Set<T>();
    void Commit();
}
```

And now you can instantiate an `AdminController` in a unit test, mock the `IUnitOfWork` dependency, and write unit tests for every controller method!

Comment: I've never *liked* DI, but I might **try** it out here. :)

Comment: Now I know why you've answered it `[RequiredRole(Roles = Constants.Roles.Moderators)]` ;-)